# attr() in CSS and its implementation

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a css style, that takes an attribute from a html tag and uses it in the css property. I've got this:

```
a[href="some_url_1"]
{
    content:attr(title url);
}
```

However this didn't work, and after some searching, I learned, that the draft of CSS, that supports this isn't implemented yet in the common browsers. (or it is implemented in a very restrictive form).
I tried to search more, but I couldn't find exactly which browsers already implements this.
Or if anyone can help me to adapt it for CSS2.1.
I do have access only to the css of the webpage, thus I cannot edit html. There is a tag:

```
<a href="some_url_1" title="some_url_2">link</a>
```

and I want to replace the text with an image with some_url_2 using css only. Is that possible with current implementation of CSS?

Comment: You don't have access to JS either?

Comment: No you are going to need to use some javascript for this.

Comment: It cannot be done using CSS only.

Comment: no JS either....only CSS

Comment: You can always do it manually if you're very desperate.

Comment: I agree with all of the above, CSS simply isn't sufficient.  Languages are, afterall, designed for specified purposes.  That being said, did you specify the doctype?  This is expand support for attribute tags in CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp